# how can i move the img dimensions from html to css and keep this slider working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have this before/after slider (the first inline image) http://whitewashed.richiesiegel.com/ and i would like to move the image dimension properties to the css, but it breaks when i do that. any idea how to resolve?

js fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/85jtY/

HTML

```
<div class="before_after_slider">
    <div class="photo">
    <div class="after">
    <img src="http://whitewashed.richiesiegel.com/images/cans.jpg" width="1000px" height="600px"  alt="after" />
    </div>
    <div class="before">
    <img src="http://whitewashed.richiesiegel.com/center_after.jpg" width="1000px" height="600px" alt="before" />
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="caption">
    <p>Roll over the photo with your cursor to see the before/after images. </p>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
.before_after_slider {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    width:1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  & > * {
    position: relative;
  }
}

.after {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  width:1000px;
  height:600px;
}

.caption {
    font-family: helvetica;
    font-weight: 100;
    line-height: 140%;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    font-size: 13px;
    width:1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;

}
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $after = $('.after'),
        img_width = $('.after img').width(),
        init_split = Math.round(img_width/2);

      $after.width(init_split);  

        $('.before_after_slider').mousemove(function(e){
        var offX  = (e.offsetX || e.clientX - $after.offset().left);
            $after.width(offX);
        });

        $('.before_after_slider').mouseleave(function(e){
        $after.stop().animate({
        width: init_split
        },200)
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sudheer105/85jtY/1/)

```
.pic{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
 }
```

added class to img attribute

Answer (score 0):

This line of your javascript...

```
img_width = $('.after img').width()
```

... is getting the width of your `img` element, but none of your css is setting the width of the `img` element, but only the `img` element wrapping `div` elements. So you need to either explicitly set the width like so...

```
.before img,
.after img {
   width: 1000px;
   height: 600px;
}
```

... or (similar to Sai Ram Sudheer's answer but without an extra class added), like so...

```
.before img,
.after img {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}
```

... which utilizes the wrapper div dimensions to size the image. The point is you have to actually give the `img` itself a size, not just the wrapper for that `img` for the `$('.after img').width()` function call to work. Then you should be able to eliminate the setting in the html.

Comment: Which version "broke"? I did not test (all is theoretical; I could not test because your fiddle does not show any images for me). The `100%` settings would break if the containers did not themselves have the necessary width/height set on them. Other than that, it should not break, as the `.width()` in jquery (I assume that is what you are using) should be reading the value that was set by the css.